# Outlook mail SaveAs (olTXT) Method wraps text after 100 characters. How do I make it longer?

Tags: vba, outlook, text-files

I use the VBA below to pull email data into a text file, but when I do the lines want to wrap after 100 characters. Since I'm scripting the resulting .txt file, this wrap makes things difficult. Is there anyway to prevent the text from wrapping or to lengthen the maximum length of the .txt file line?

```
Sub saveEmail(Msg As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
Dim dtDate As Date
dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd ")
saveFolder = "C:\Users\########\AppData\Local\Temp\"

  ' assume an email is selected
  Set Msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

  dtDate = Msg.ReceivedTime
   sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, " (hh-nn-ss)", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)

  ' save as text
  Msg.SaveAs saveFolder & "\" & "New Matter Report.txt", olTXT
  Call SendMessage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look through the message properties and build your own text file instead of relying on the SaveAs method.

Comment: boss says we need to automate this

Comment: @NateMay Maybe the message was not open in plain text mode and that's why it wraps. Look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868727.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The question: [Outlook "save message as text" without line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527988/outlook-save-message-as-text-without-line-breaks/48800032#48800032) points to a method for Adjusting the point at which text is wrapped which gives you some control (in OL 2013 Options | Mail | Message format) In the proposed answers for that question there is a reference to [another discussion of the topic](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/84759-line-breaks-added-to-text-file/) in which it is suggested that the FileSystem object be used instead. I haven't found a way to avoid the SaveAs including line breaks.