# Outlook "save message as text" without line breaks

Tags: outlook

I receive emails where the body contains raw data (long csv lines) from an external application. I want to store this data in a text file. However, when I store it (File->Save As->txt) Outlook automatically inserts line breaks at the position specified in the Outlook Options "Automatically wrap text at character". This cannot be set to anything higher than 132, and the remove extra line breaks does nothing when saving data.

Is there any way I can fix this or do I have to use another mail client than Outlook?

[image: Outlook options]

Comment: I upgraded and changed tool on the sender side so it made a proper mail attachment. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Through the GUI it may not be possible but one solution to this problem 
is to use something other than the MailItem.SaveAs command in vba (macro code). https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/84759-line-breaks-added-to-text-file/

Comment: Link is broken, so this answer is no longer useful.